# SQL - How to select the most occurring entry from one column and list it with another column?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am trying to select the most sold item from the column Product_ID (FK) which should be listed together with a BRANCH_ID (FK) e.g The most sold item for branch 1, then the most sold item for branch 2 etc. These are all in my table called SALES.

Is there a query that allows me to do this?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: If you added the table structure and example data and expected output...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one row is one order item then something like this would help:

```
SELECT
    s.branch_id
  , s.product_id
  , s.qnty
FROM (
    SELECT
        branch_id
      , s.product_id
      , COUNT(*) AS qnty
      , RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY s.branch_id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS [rank]
    FROM dbo.sales AS s
    GROUP BY s.branch_id, s.product_id
) s
WHERE s.rank = 1
ORDER BY branch_id
```

If two items sold the same amount they will both appear.

Without table definition I can't help you further.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL:

```sql
select distinct s1.BRANCH_ID, s1.Product_ID
from SALES s1
where s1.Product_ID = (
    select s2.Product_ID
    from SALES s2
    where s2.BRANCH_ID = s1.BRANCH_ID
    group by s2.Product_ID
    order by count(1) desc
    limit 1
);
```

Or better:

```sql
select b.BRANCH_ID, (
    select s2.Product_ID
    from SALES s2
    where s2.BRANCH_ID = b.BRANCH_ID
    group by s2.Product_ID
    order by count(1) desc
    limit 1
) as Product_ID
from BRANCHES b;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5aaf65/4